# SSRS Pie chart hide 0 Value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

SQL Server 2012 - SSRS Questions

I currently have a Pie chart that shows the number of deliveries as a percentage on whether they are late, on time or early.  What I am trying to do is use an Expression in the Chart Series Labels "Visible" property to hide the label if it is 0 on the chat.  Of note in the table this value is returned as 0.00  I have tried using various SWITCH and IFF Statements to do this but nothing seems to work and its likely I am getting the syntax wrong, can anyone help?

**Table Values**

TotalIssued Early Late OnTime EarlyPerc LatePerc OnTimePerc 
6,      0,    4,    2,      0.00,   66.67,   33.33,

```
 =SWITCH(
 (First(Fields!EarlyPerc.Value, "EstimatesIssued") = 0),false,
 (First(Fields!LatePerc.Value, "EstimatesIssued") = 0),false,
 (First(Fields!OnTimePerc.Value, "EstimatesIssued") = 0),false,
 true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=SWITCH(
 First(Fields!EarlyPerc.Value, "EstimatesIssued") = 0,false,
 First(Fields!LatePerc.Value, "EstimatesIssued") = 0,false,
 First(Fields!OnTimePerc.Value, "EstimatesIssued") = 0,false,
 true,true)
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have one field per percentage and your dataset returns one row always, you have to select each serie in the ChartData window and press `F4` to see properties window.

In properties window set for `EarlyPerc` `Visible` property:

```
=IIF(Fields!EarlyPerc.Value=0,False,True)
```

And so on for the next two series you have (LatePerc and OnTimePerc).

[image] [image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That has worked exactly as I wanted and a lot easier than what I was trying to do, you would of hoped though that there would of been an option to do this a the series data label level as if you had a lot of different series this could take some time.  For now though this is brilliant, thanks for your help